# yii captcha not validating properly

Tags: php, validation, yii, captcha

Im trying to add a captcha using yii to my contact form, but there is some problem with validation.

My model

```
class ContactForm extends CFormModel
{
  public $verifyCode;

 public function rules()
{
    return array(

        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'on'=>'captchaRequired'),
        array('verifyCode', 'safe'),
                );
}
}
```

Code in my controller

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl',
    );
}



public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
            array(  'allow', //allow all users to perform advertise and index action 
                    'actions' => array('advertise','index', 'captcha'),
        'users' => array('*'),
            ),
    );
}

 public function actions() {
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
        'captcha' => array(
            'class' => 'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor' => 0xFFFFFF,
            'testLimit'=> '2',
        ),
      )
}

 public actionAdvertise()
 {   $model = new ContactForm;
    $model->scenario = 'captchaRequired';
    if($model->validate()){
   //some code
    }  else {
            $this->render('advertise', array('model' => $model));
    }
 }
}
```

Code in my advertise.php view

```
 <form action="" method="post">
            <?php
               $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
                    'id'=>'contact-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
                ));
            ?>
           <?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()){ ?>  
               <div class="row">
         <div class="contact_field_wrapper">
              <?php echo '<b>ARE YOU HUMAN?</b><br />'.$form->labelEx($model, 'verifyCode'); ?> 
<div class="captcha user-captcha">
         <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha',array(  'captchaAction'=>'site/captcha' ));                                                                                         
  ?>
                                <?php echo $form->error($model, 'verifyCode'); ?>
                                <?php  echo '<br />'.$form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
                                <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.<br/>
                                    Letters are not case-sensitive.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
<?php } ?>
 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</form>
```

The problem is that `$model->validate()` returns false when correct code in inputted.
`$model->getErrors()` is always returning **'Verification code is incorrect'.**

Comment: Is there a way to debug this problem somehow?

Comment: your model is empty and validate returns false

Comment: is 'contact' the name of the form? Im not storing any value in database

Comment: Thank you so much! that did the trick. I added if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']){ $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];}  Can you mention it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your model is empty , because you didn't pass any value to `$model->attriburtes`

Do this :

```
if($_POST['ContactForm'])
{
     $model->attributes() = $_POST['ContactForm'];
     if($model->validate())
     {
           //some code
     }
}
$this->render('advertise', array('model' => $model));
```