# How can I set safe or allow empty captcha on scenario?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to set safe or allow empty captcha on scenario like bellow code.

```
 public function rules() {
        return [
            [['verifyCode'], 'safe', 'on'=>'admin'],
        ];
    }
```

But it does not work, and I got this error.

```
Invalid CAPTCHA action ID: site/captcha
```

and also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691198/yii-captcha-not-validating-properly) didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Add rule:

```
[['verifyCode'], 'captcha', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'on'=>'admin']
```

In controller, when create instance:

```
$model->scenario = 'admin';
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I have used allowEmpty based on the page that I linked it.


what is allowEmpty use for?

Comment: `allowEmpty` this property is true for version Yii 1.1